# Preventing purrr::map error when function returns NULL

Tags: r, purrr

I'd like to use the map_chr function on a dataset like so

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x) if(x == "a") NULL else "blah"
f("a") # returns NULL

# make tibble
mytib <- tibble(test = c("a", "b"))

# naive map_chr
mytib %>% mutate(getf = map_chr(test, f))

# with .default
mytib %>% mutate(getf = map_chr(test, f, .default = NA_character_))
```

As you can see, map_chr fails with error message `` Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `getf`. x unused argument (.default = NA) ``.

Attempts with possibly and na_if as described elsewhere didn't work for me either.

How can I get map_chr to loop over the arguments and leave NULL values to be NA_character_ or some other value?

Comment: You need `mytib %>% mutate(getf = map(test, f))` and return a list column  The `NULL` doesn't have any length.  You could have defined the `f` as `f <- function(x) if(x == "a") NA_character_ else "blah"` or can be vectorized with `ifelse` or `case_when`

Comment: Is there no way to go directly to a character column?

Comment: It depends on why you specify `NULL` return instead would be `NA_character_` and then `map_chr` works fine

Comment: So if the function ```f``` is defined to return NULL, I'd have to write a wrapper that returns ```NA```?

Comment: Or something like `mytib %>% mutate(getf = map_chr(test, ~ {tmp <- f(.x); replace(tmp, is.null(tmp), NA_character_)}))`

Comment: Or use `mytib %>% mutate(getf = map_chr(test, ~ c(f(.x), NA_character_)[1]))`

Comment: What does ```map_chr(test, ~ c(f(.x), NA_character_)[1]))``` do? Particularly the ```c(f(.x)``` and the ```[1]``` part?

Comment: In the solution posted, I described about the use of `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to define the `f` to return `NA_character_`

```
 f <- function(x) if(x == "a") NA_character_ else "blah"
```

and then the OP's call works as expected

Or instead of looping, create a vectorized function

```
f <- function(x) case_when(x != 'a' ~ 'blah')
```

and then call as

```
mytib %>% 
       mutate(getf = f(test))
```

---

Or another option if the `f` is already defined to return `NULL`, then concatenate with `NA` and extract the first element.  `NULL` doesn't have any `length`, so concatenating with `NA` returns `NA` only

```
c(NULL, NA_character_)
#[1] NA

mytib %>% 
   mutate(getf = map_chr(test, ~ c(f(.x), NA_character_)[1]))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  test  getf 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     <NA> 
#2 b     blah
```

The `[1]` index is to extract those cases where there is actual values 'blah' returns, so that we select only the first element i.e. 'blah' and for those with `if` condition is `TRUE`, it will anyway return only NA_character_

Comment: The second solution is a brilliant hack! I wish ```map_chr``` had a built-in solution.

Comment: @TeaTree There is a `map_if` option, but it is also need a predicate function

Answer (score 0):

`purrr::map_chr()` will try to convert the list output to a `character` vector, if you try to convert a `NULL` object to a character you get something like this:

```
as.character(NULL)
#> character(0)
```

Which is a vector with length 0. Moreover, NULL is not valid object type for this function. By the other hand, this is what you get if try to convert a `NA_character_` to `character.`.

```
as.character(NA_character_)
#> NA
```

You can try this:

```
library(purrr)

f <- function(x) if(x == "a") NA_character_ else "blah"

# make tibble
mytib <- tibble(test = c("a", "b"))

# naive map_chr
mytib %>% mutate(getf = map_chr(test, f))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  test  getf 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     NA   
#2 b     blah
```